# Well structured organization of jars - is it possible for a set of projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

Here and on the net I see much advice about how to put jars into a project. [There are many ways for it](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29). But a real life Project consists of many eclipse projects. And many of them have same jars.

I have one real project consisting of a few (a dozen) java projects. And the Ant is used for building.

I want to keep my and standard jars so:

1. It should be some understandable structure,
2. Jars should be easy to reach for referencing (excellent if I can include them by groups)
3. Jars should be easy and safe to update. I would like to minimize the possibility of having two jars of different versions in different projects

If I reference the projects from each other, I will quickly come to loop references. If I put every jar physically into each project, it is bad because of duplicity - later I will surely forget to update the jar in some of the projects. If I put a jar into some project physically and reference it from others, later I will have to search, where the appropriate jar is, in order to update is. The only structure that I had managed to think of, is to divide jar into some subsystems, make extra projects (library projects), that will contain these jars and to reference these projects from the real ones.

But maybe Eclipse or Ant have some automated solution?

(If it is impossible, can IntelliJIdea or Maven or Gradle or something else do the thing?)

Again, please, notice, I am NOT talking about how to put jars into a project, but about how to organize them in a set of projects.

Comment: I don’t understand this question: what is “organizing” JAR files supposed to solve?

Comment: @Bombe I have put there 3 requirements. Are they not enough?

Comment: Three requirements might be enough if they made any sense which these don’t. What is an “understandable structure”? Structure of what? Understandable to whom? How can a JAR file be “easy for referencing?” How do you want to include what who now “in groups?” How is a JAR “easy and safe to update?” Does it defend itself with a shotgun against being updated? So, no, your requirements seem contrived and artificial. I suspect you are trying to do dependency management here: look into maven, or Gradle, and stop caring about where they get their JAR files from and where they put them. :)

Comment: @Bombe -Sigh-. If I could use Maven or Gradle, I wouldn't ask that question... Easy for referencing means that structure doesn't make the referencing more complicated that it is. Structure of what? - that is the main subject of the question. Don't repeat it :-). Safe for update? I have explained it - no duplicates. no shotguns, simple control against duplication is enough. You are in search for the purer code? Excellent! It is exactly what I am talking about - how to change that long-lists-with-same-jars way for smth more pure.

Comment: we’re going in circles. Unless you’re getting a lot clearer on what you want to achieve, I can’t help you.

Comment: Modern build tools like Maven and Gradle give you this capability, your build file states project dependencies and resolvers will work out the complex tree of dependencies and ensuring that one copy is used. This is not a trivial problem to solve.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor That's why I thought about creation of separate project/s that would serve as a jar library/ies. I only expected that somebody did try such optimization and can advice.

Comment: Not entirely clear the problem you're trying to solve. If each project can be built independently, that is a good thing and enables your team to scale up. If each project publishes to a Maven repository your development team can easily share jars with each other. The SNAPSHOT revision capability in Maven is designed to support this. In this scenario the Maven repository holds both jars built by your teams and jars built by 3rd parties and used as dependencies.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I  know that Maven is good, thank you. And I would be happy to use it or Gradle. But I have already said, and I am repeating for the third time here, I **must** use Ant. This is a demand of the client.

Comment: And..... Ant has a plugin called ivy designed to do dependency management. Maven repositories are used by more than just Maven the build tool. Checkout products like Nexus and Artifactory,.... Good day to you